# Как собрать и обновить ядро Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

Как правильно собрать ядро линукса в .deb файл и обновить уже им, само установление ядро или - как вообще, собрать и обновить ядро.

Comment: [официальная документация](https://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/amd64/ch08s06.html.ru) вам обязательно поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации этот процесс [довольно подробно изложен, причём по-русски](https://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/amd64/ch08s06.html.ru).

Ещё больше подробностей (но по-английски) можно найти в [Debian Linux Kernel Handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/).

---

**Замечание**: копировать текст из первой ссылки я смысла не вижу — во-первых, он великоват для ответа, во-вторых, если уж сайт `debian.org` перестанет работать, то, скорее всего, и инструкция по сборке *deb*-пакета с *linux*-ом уже вряд ли будет кому-нибудь нужна.

Comment: При выполнение задачи, показало ошибку:

`/root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14/scripts/Makefile.headersinst:55: *** Missing UAPI file /root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h.  Stop.
make[4]: *** [netfilter] Error 2
make[3]: *** [linux] Error 2
make[2]: *** [headers_install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [vmlinux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14'
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2`

Comment: @Insider, задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос по поводу этой ошибки, не забыв изложить все свои действия.