# Не найден (существующий!) файл при сборке

Tags: linux, kernel

Вчера задавал вопрос: [Как собрать и обновить ядро Linux?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451655/178576)

Следовал по инструкции:

Для начала установил нужные мне пакеты - `fakeroot, kernel-package`

Скачал само [ядро](https://github.com/SolidRun/linux-imx6-3.14)

Настроил его так, как мне нужно, и ввел следующую команду:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --revision=custom.1.0 kernel_image
```

Как прошло некоторое время, в консоли вылезла такая ошибка:

> /root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14/scripts/Makefile.headersinst:55: *** Missing UAPI file /root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h.  Stop. make[4]:**  [netfilter] Error 2 make[3]:  **[linux] Error 2 make[2]:**  [headers_install] Error 2 make[1](https://github.com/SolidRun/linux-imx6-3.14):  **[vmlinux] Error 2 make[1](https://github.com/SolidRun/linux-imx6-3.14): Leaving directory `/root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14' make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2

Как её исправить?

Comment: каталог `/root/usb/linux-imx6-3.14/include/uapi/linux/netfilter/` существует? если да, то на какой файловой системе он располагается?

Comment: Архив существует, FAT32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы развернули архив на файловой системе, не чувствительной к регистру символов в именах файлов/каталогов.

поэтому имя файла `xt_CONNMARK.h` «превратилось» в «безрегистровое» `xt_connmark.h` (или `XT_CONNMARK.H`, в зависимости от опций монтирования) и файл «не находится».

во избежание подобных «ошибок» используйте файловую систему, чувствительную к регистру символов: например, [`ext*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_system), или, в совсем уж крайнем случае, [`ntfs`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100625).

---

архив надо будет распаковать заново — простое копирование файлов не «восстановит» утерянную информацию.

Comment: появилась ошибка. мне создавать новую тему?

Comment: другая ошибка? тогда, конечно, это новый вопрос.

Comment: ошибка во время сборки ядра.