# Как собрать/сделать ядро со следующими параметрами?

Tags: linux, kernel

Необходимо чтобы ядро было вот с такими параметрами:

```
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
```

Что мне для этого необходимо сделать?

Comment: найдите инструкцию по сборке ядра, после выполнения make menuconfig попадёте в текстовую оболочку конкурирования, в ней есть функция поиска параметров по их имени, воспользуйтесь ей чтоб найти и установить нужные вам параметры в необходимое состояние.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что мне для этого необходимо сделать?

необходимо добавить эти строки в файл `.config` после его создания.

все остальные действия по сборке программы *linux* — как обычно (получить исходники, сформировать `.config`, собрать (вызвав программу *make*)).

Comment: Эм, извините за нубство, но мне так близко с ядром работать никогда не приходилось. Этот файл вообще где создать? Как бы ядро уже собрано, стоит. работает. И вот, необходимо поставить тулзу, а там такое дело. Необходимы эти параметры.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451655/178576

Comment: я правильно понял, что .config надо создать в том же каталоге, где буду ядро собирать с указанными параметрами, а далее как обычно, да?

Comment: нет, файл конфигурации надо копировать в тот каталог, в котором распакованы исходные тексты (я просто не знаю, что вы подразумеваете под «каталог, где буду ядро собирать»).

Comment: если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью соответствующей кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если каталоги сборки и исходников различны, то конфиг как раз должен лежать как раз в «каталоге, где буду ядро собирать», а не с исходниками...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я не в курсе, что вы и автор вопроса можете подразумевать под «каталогом сборки». единственное, что приходит на ум — это текущий каталог в случае использования опции `-C` программы *make*. `.config` должен располагаться в этом случае не в текущем каталоге, а именно в том каталоге, в котором распакованы исходники программы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, из `make help` ядра: `make O=dir [targets] Locate all output files in "dir", including .config`. Т.е. это позволяет, как и для большинства современных систем сборки, собирать ядро в отдельным каталоге ничего не записывая (и даже не имея прав на это) в каталог с исходниками... я подразумевал именно эту возможность... `-C` при сборке ядра имеет несколько другую семантику...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну, что вы подразумевали под термином «каталог сборки», теперь понятно. осталось узнать, что под этим термином подразумевал автор вопроса.